# Is using two nested WHERE clauses ok?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my query:

```
    $first = DB::table('news')
        ->selectRaw('"news" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q));
        });

    $results = DB::table('productions')
        ->selectRaw('"productions" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q));
        })
        ->unionAll($first)
        ->get();
```

As you see, there is a `where()` and also there is a `whereRaw()` in it .. is it correct?

The result is ok, I mean it is exactly as expected .. just I'm worried about the performance. you know, I guess I can do that by only one `where()`. However currently it works as well, but I scare if the dataset be huge, then it maybe it will be slow.

Anyway, is my code good?

Comment: I don't know why you use a closure for only one condition. But it doesn't matter in terms of sql performance, because it will construct the same sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add single where in `where()` closure. You can write your code without that also as:

```
$first = DB::table('news')
    ->selectRaw('"news" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
    ->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q));

$results = DB::table('productions')
    ->selectRaw('"productions" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
    ->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q));
    ->unionAll($first)
    ->get();
```

But if you're really concern about the performance when dataset becomes huge then I advise you to use `paginate()` function instead of `get()`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing I'd say is particularly wrong with it in terms of functionality, but there are somethings you could clean up, e.g. you're doing a selectRaw just so you can alias the table, but you're never using the alias.

```
$first = DB::table('news')
    ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
    ->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");

$results = DB::table('productions')
    ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
    ->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->unionAll($first)
    ->get();
```

Try the above, if this doesn't work try your code but replace your selectRaw statements with the select statements.

Comment: It's not a table alias, it's a column containing the table name.

Comment: Ah you're right, sorry. In which case the select statement could be `->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath', 'news'])` the same for production but switch out 'news' for 'productions', I'm not entirely sure of your implementation of it but it's most likely easier to read with the attribute being called 'news' or 'productions' than 'tableName'. However, if you're set on having it called 'tableName' sure again functionality wise it shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't work. The DB would try to select the column `news` from the `news` table and column `productions` from `productions` table. But those columns do probably not exist. What OP wants is a column `tableName` with hard coded values 'news' and 'productions' depending on from what table the row comes from.

Comment: Are you sure that's what he wants? From the way the question is worded the code he has provided does exactly what is required he just wants to refactor it, so I would assume that the news and productions columns do exist within their respective tables.